# my python functions do not work in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i have written lines of code that run normally in jupyter notebook (here is the code below):

```
umd_departments = requests.get("https://api.umd.io/v0/courses/departments")
umd_departments_list = umd_departments.json()

umd_departments_list2 = json.dumps(umd_departments_list, indent=1)
department_storage = [department['dept_id'] for department in umd_departments_list]
print(department_storage)
```

the code above usually gives me the output i want and prints it out immediately. the issue i run into is when i try and put the code above into a function of its own it doesn't work

```
def get_UMD_departments():
    umd_departments = requests.get("https://api.umd.io/v0/courses/departments")
    umd_departments_list = umd_departments.json()
    umd_departments_list2 = json.dumps(umd_departments_list, indent=1)
    department_storage = [department['dept_id'] for department in umd_departments_list]
    print(department_storage)
```

the problem i face with this version of  code  is that it never prints out anything as oppose to the other code i showed. with this code, i also don't get an error when i run it  since the * symbol doesn't show up and i don't get an error message. so i'm not sure what the problem is. it usually just shows how many times i ran the cell. i was wondering if anyone knew a way to make the function version of my code to work, greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you call the `get_UMD_departments` function?

Comment: yeah that  was my mistake, i didn't call the function lol @Ammar

Comment: _yeah that was my mistake, i didn't call the function_ Voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced.